# Azure Function not returning XML response

Tags: c#, json, xml, asp.net-mvc, azure-functions

I am unable to return result object as XML. As I understand from the documentation, `JsonResult` formats the given object as JSON. However `ObjectResult` has content negotiation built in.

Despite both `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers set in the request to `application/xml`, the function always serialises the response object as JSON.

```cs
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    ResponseMessage responseObject = new ResponseMessage
    {
        Code = "111",
        Message = "This response shall be XML formatted"
    };

    return new ObjectResult(responseObject);
}
```

I found the post [Can Azure Functions return XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538324/can-azure-functions-return-xml) which mentions that proper content negotiation is coming, so I assume that after 5 years in .Net Core 3.1 shall support this.

EDIT:

The code I was testing was run locally. Just noticed that the same code put into hosted Azure Function via "Develop in Portal" works perfectly and returns expected XML when `Accept:application/xml` is set in the request. `Accept` is sufficient condition, `Content-Type` does not need to be set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Function not returning XML response

The easiest way is to rely on Content Result

```
[FunctionName("ContentResultWithXmlInString")]
public static IActionResult Run4([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
{
    string xmlContent = File.ReadAllText("xmlcontent.xml");            
    return new ContentResult { Content = xmlContent, ContentType = "application/xml" };
}



  GET http://localhost:7071/api/ContentResultWithXmlInString HTTP/1.1
    User-Agent: Fiddler
    Host: localhost:7071
    Accept: application/xml
    
    
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Fri, 25 May 2018 22:16:58 GMT
    Content-Type: application/xml
    Server: Kestrel
    Content-Length: 232
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <MyData xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HttpReturnXml">
      <Property1>Foo</Property1>
      <Property2>3</Property2>
    </MyData>
```

You will get xml into string and then put that string into OKObjectResult

for further information refer [XML response](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2896)

Answer (score 0):

In an Azure Function Net7 isolated, you have to take care of setting the Content-Type of the request and then send as a string. This method that has been working in production.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    
    var xml = @"<note>
                        <to>Customer</to>
                        <from>Sender</from>
                        <heading>Reminder</heading>
                        <body>Message</body>
                        </note>";
    
    HttpResponseData? response;
    response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
    response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    await response.WriteStringAsync(xml);   

    return response;
    
}
```